# How to write a generator for this function

Tags: python

For some bizarre reason, I am struggling to get my head around iterators/generators as used in Python (I write/use them with no problem in C++ - but somehow I can't seem to grok how to write one using Python).

I have a mathematical function of the form:

`f(a,b) = ( v1(a) - v1(b) ) / ( v2(a) - v2(b) )`

Where v1 and v2 are equal length 1D vectors.

I want to write a function (actually, a generator), that generates the output of f() as defined above.

Can anyone help?

**[[Edit]]**

My notation may have been confusing. I hope to clarify that. The function described above return a **set** of values. With the argument b taking on values, in the interval `(a,b]`

So for example if we call `f(1,5)`, the function will return the following **values** (not functions -in case my clarification below causes further confusion):

```
f(1,1)
f(1,2)
f(1,3)
f(1,4)
f(1,5)
```

Comment: Why do you need a generator for that?

Comment: There's nothing iterative in that calculation. What exactly do you want to use the generator *for*?

Comment: @Tadeck: I have clarified the question in light of your question. Please see above.

Comment: If you write/use them with no problem in C++, you probably don't understand what the Python concepts are. *C++ doesn't have them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generator expression:

```
def f(a, b):
  return ((v1[a] - v1[i]) / (v2[a] - v2[i]) for i in xrange(a, b+1))
```

Or a generator function

```
def f(a, b):
  for i in xrange(a, b+1)
    yield (v1[a] - v1[i]) / (v2[a] - v2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The generator may look like that, since there is no iteration (as [kindall correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574760/how-to-write-a-generator-for-this-function#comment13692021_10574760)).

```py
def f(a, b):
    yield (v1[a] - v1[b]) / (v2[a] - v2[b])  # be careful about division!
```

Couple notes:

- there is nothing to iterate through, and generators are generally used in iterations,
- be careful about divisions: in Python 2.x `a / b` returns integer if both `a` and `b` are integers (so `4 / 3 == 1`) - you can avoid this by using `float`s or by `from __future__ import division`,